# How can I retrieve a Featured Image thumbnail using only the Post_title?

Tags: post-thumbnails, title

Is it possible to get the Wordpress featured image of a post using only the post_title name?
I know it can be done with post->ID but I only have the post_title name to work with and this is outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
/**
 * Get the featured image by post title (Simple version)
 * 
 * @see    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158344/26350
 * @param  string $title   Post title
 * @param  mixed  $size    Featured image size
 */

function get_featured_image_by_post_title_wpse_simple( $title = '', $size = 'thumbnail' )
{
    $obj  =  get_page_by_title( $title, OBJECT, 'post' );
    return ( is_object ( $obj ) ) ? get_the_post_thumbnail( $obj->ID, $size ) : '';
}
```

or this extended version:

```
/**
 * Get the featured image by post title (Extended version)
 *
 * @see    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158344/26350
 * @param  string $title     Post title
 * @param  mixed  $size      Featured image size
 * @param  string $post_type Post type
 * @param  string $default   Default image url
 * @return string $html      Featured image HTML
 */

function get_featured_image_by_post_title_wpse_ext( $title = '', $size = 'thumbnail', $post_type = 'post', $default = '' )
{
    // Search by post title:
    $obj  = get_page_by_title( $title, OBJECT, $post_type );

    // Featured image:
    if( is_object( $obj ) && has_post_thumbnail( $obj->ID ) )
        $html = get_the_post_thumbnail( $obj->ID, $size );
    else     
        $html = sprintf( '<img src="%s" alt="">', esc_url( $default ) );

    return $html;
}
```

where use [`get_page_by_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) to locate the post by title.

**Usage examples:**

```
 // Simple:
 echo get_featured_image_by_post_title_wpse_simple( 'Hello World!', 'large' );

 // Extended:
 echo get_featured_image_by_post_title_wpse_ext( 'My Car', 'full', 'post', '/car.jpg' );
```

Hopefully you can extend this to your needs.